# Save Canvas image to the device/gallery on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have been trying for a few days now to take an image from the Canvas of my application and save that to the device... I've tried some (with no result) plugins like: Save2Canvas, Base64 To Gallery, Canvas2ImagePlugin and Cordova base64ToGallery Plugin...

I am using:
Cordova 7.0.1
Ionic 1.x

Right now the part of my Js. function to save is like this

```
 var image = canvas
    .toDataURL("image/png");
    window.location.href=image;
```

Which kind of works on ionic 1.x via browser but not on the device...

Comment: Use fromDataURL('your image path goes here...') and in options set your saveToPhotoAlbum: true. This should do...Worked for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using [canvas2ImagePlugin](https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin)(that you mentioned). This worked for me for saving my canvas content to gallery.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"  width="165px" height="145px" ></canvas>

<script>
    //get the canvas element
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

    //save to Gallery
    window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
        function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
        },
        function(err){
            console.log(err);
        },
        document.getElementById('myCanvas')
    );  

</script>
```

Comment: It worked! But the image is kinda low quality, do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Depends on the quality of canvas content. It takes everything from there and tries to create an image and save it. When we tried this plugin for video snapshots, the quality of images depended purely on the quality of the video that is being played. (may be because we were drawing canvas from that). Hope this helps. :)